# How to solve 'Client is immutable when created with the builder'?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am creating an application where want to upload a file to S3 bucket.
I am getting an error from following code snippet:

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("<myKey>", "<mySecretId>");
                                AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                                        .withRegion("<myRegion>")
                                        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                                        .build();

                                PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest("testbucketupdate", "testFile", new File("D:\\Attachments\\LICENSE"));
                                ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
                                metadata.setContentType("plain/text");
                                metadata.addUserMetadata("x-amz-meta-title", "someTitle");
                                request.setMetadata(metadata);
                                s3Client.setS3ClientOptions(S3ClientOptions.builder().setPathStyleAccess(true).disableChunkedEncoding().build());
                                s3Client.putObject(request);
```

I am getting an error as:

```
Java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Client is immutable when created with the builder.
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.checkMutability(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:937)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.setS3ClientOptions(AmazonS3Client.java:716)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler.check(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:123)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler.main(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:208)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler.handleRequest(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:51)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler.handleRequest(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:1)
    at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$PojoHandlerAsStreamHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:178)
    at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:888)
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:283)
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:64)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:94)
```

What changes I should make to upload a file successfully to the required bucket?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Obviously the error says that if you use the `AmazonS3ClientBuilder` to build a client, it will be immutable and you can't modify it after it is built.

The solution is to remove later `s3Client.setS3ClientOptions(...)` and to set required options using the `AmazonS3ClientBuilder` builder. Something along the lines:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
    .withRegion("<myRegion>")
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
    .enablePathStyleAccess()
    .disableChunkedEncoding()
    .build();
```