# com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to calculate MD5 hash: /home/bharath/Documents/demo/demo.txt (No such file or directory)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

By taking the reference of this Question link below

> [How to solve 'Client is immutable when created with the builder'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50738615/how-to-solve-client-is-immutable-when-created-with-the-builder/52282947?noredirect=1#comment91514768_52282947)

I do have a similar code structure wherein which am getting an error saying

> Unable to calculate MD5 hash

```
public class LambdaFunctionS3 implements RequestHandler<Object, String> {
@Override
public String handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {
    context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);
    String clientRegion = "ap-south-1";
    String bucketName = "Bucket Name";
    String fileObjKeyName = "demo.txt";
    String fileName = "/home/bharath/Documents/demo/demo.txt";
    try {
    System.out.println("Uploading a new file to s3 bucket...");
    File file = new File(fileName);
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(clientRegion)
            .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
            .build(); 
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileObjKeyName,file);
            ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            metadata.setContentType("plain/text");
            metadata.addUserMetadata("x-amz-meta-title", "myFunction");
            request.setMetadata(metadata);
            s3Client.putObject(request);
            System.out.println("File uploaded.");
            return "Success";

    } catch(AmazonServiceException e) {      
        System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
        System.exit(1);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(SdkClientException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
 return "Hello from Lambda!";  }
```

Though I have a file with the correct path. Am using aws lambda function in order to upload a file in s3.

Any help?

Comment: Why do you think that Lambda can access your local file system?

Comment: Hi, @stdunbar thanks for your time. Am new to lambda though i have done file uploads into s3 using java SDK without any lambda function. I started following this official documentation of amazon [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html ]. I might be wrong with my understanding. Please help me out.